# rendering multiple templates

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm learning Backbone and Underscore right now and I'm making a little mock email app.

I managed to pass a `JSON` collection of Email to my view and displayed it in a unordered list. What I want is to click on an item and have a separate template rendered next to my list displaying the content of the email.

Code snippet from my view:

the html templates:

```
<div>
    <h1>Backbone test data bind to view</h1>
    <hr/>
    <div class="page">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/template" id="email-list-template-styled">       
<div class="tab">
    <ul>
        <@ _.each(emails, function(email){ @>
            <a class="tablinks" data-id="<@= email.get('id') @>" href="backbone" >
                <td> From: <@= email.get('sender') @> </td> </br>
                <td> To: <@= email.get('recipient') @> </td> </br>
                <td> Date: <@= email.get('dateSent') @> </td> </br>
            </a>
        <@ }) @>
    </ul>
</div>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="email-content">
    <div id="emailContent" class="tabcontent">
        <h3>From: sender</h3>
        <h3>To: recipient</h3>
        <h3>Subject: subject</h3>
        <h3>Date: dateSent</h3>
        <p>message</p>
    </div>
</script>
```

Java script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var EmailsList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url : 'backbone/getEmails.html'
});

var Email = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var EmailList = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.page',
    events: {
         'click' : 'showAlert'

        },
        showAlert: function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var that = this;
            var id = $(event.target).data('id');
            var Email = Backbone.Model.extend({
                url: 'backbone/getEmail/' + id
            });

            var email = new Email();
            email.fetch({
                success: function(email){
                    console.log(email.toJSON());
                    var template = _.template($('#email-content').html(), {email: email.models} );
                    that.$el.append(template);
                }
            })
        },

    render: function(){
        var that = this;
        var emails = new EmailsList();
        emails.fetch({
            success : function(emails) {
                console.log(emails.toJSON());
                var template = _.template($('#email-list-template-styled').html(), {emails: emails.models} );
                that.$el.html(template);
            }
        })
    }
});

var emailList = new EmailList();

var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes:{
        '': 'backbone'
    }
})

var router = new Router();
router.on('route:backbone', function(){
    emailList.render();
});

Backbone.history.start();
</script>
```

Single object data example:

```
dateSent:"2017-03-21 08:36"
id:3
message:"Message3"
recipient:"Recipient3"
sender:"Sender3"
subject:"Subject3"
```

So far I've managed to get the id of the Email I'm clicking to the click event.
Than I tried to render a template passing the single email object (i get the correct email `JSON`), I'm appending the template so at the moment it creates multiple instances and i cant seem to get variables printed in the `email-content` template. I get an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined` when i type in something like:

```
<h3>From: sender <@= email.get('sender') @></h3>
```

So the questions would be:

How can I re render the content template

How do I access the email variable in the content template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is using old `underscore.js` versions syntax, if you're using new version then that's an issue, use the new syntax:

```
var template = _.template(templateString);
template(data);
```

and in the below line:

```
var template = _.template($('#email-content').html(), {email: email.models} );
```

email is a model, not a collection.

So your code should be:

```
var template = _.template($('#email-content').html(), {email: email} );
```

Now you will be able to do `<h3>From: sender <@= email.get('sender') @></h3>`.

I suggest doing:

```
var template = _.template($('#email-content').html(), {email: email.toJSON()} );
```

and rendering like `<h3>From: sender <@= email.sender @></h3>` just to make sure templating stuff doesn't affect original modal.

---

Also, you shouldn't define modal constructor in an event handler

```
var Email = Backbone.Model.extend({
   url: 'backbone/getEmail/' + id
});
```

Instead define your model like

```
var Email = Backbone.Model.extend({
   urlRoot: 'backbone/getEmail/'
});
```

and set `id` on the model. Backbone will append `id` to `url`.

Setting `urlRoot` is not necessary if you pass `{model: Email}` to the collection, and find the matching model from the collection using it's `get()` method than creating new model instance every time, which is the proper way to do it imo.

Other suggestions:

- Define a separate view for the detailed view of email
- Avoid using `el` property if you're new to Backbone
- Upgrade to new version of `underscore.js` and cache the template function in view's `template` property
- Make the event listenr `'click' : 'showAlert'` more specific like `'click .email' : 'showAlert'`. Otherwise clicking anywhere in the view will trigger the handler. If user clicks on an element which is not an actual email with data `id` (like a dropdown or something) it'll cause bugs

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Removing .models from email helped. Im now able to display the data.

moved Email from the event 

`var Email = Backbone.Model.extend({
 urlRoot: 'backbone/getEmail/'
});`

Comment: If i define a different view for the details how do i pass the selected email to the view?

Comment: @mindz `showAlert: function(e){ this.emailView = new EmailView({model: model})}`. And you can append EmailView `el` to  EmailListView `el`, or some specific container. You can even have the EmailListView trigger and event like `this.trigger('show-email', {id: id});` and listen to it from somewhere else in your application and initialize the EmailDetailView using model id from event data

Comment: @mindz I'd keep the emailList view and emailDetails view as decoupled as possible. Also see the last suggestion about event listener.

Comment: Thanks every one. I did keep them separate and did as suggested above. Works great :)